How to change default row hover color in a selected row with AgGridReact
I need to remove the row color when a row is selected and hovered over in AgGrid tables using React. The problem is that when I select a row and hover over some of its elements, a default dark gray color is applied, which I don't want in my code.
The code being used is a React code with CSS and Material.
Idk if I can modify something of my code or something in the gridoptions of the AgGrid table.
Thanks you for the asnwers.
.ag-theme-material .ag-root-wrapper {
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.ag-theme-material .ag-cell:hover {
    background-color: #F3F9FB !important; 
}

.ag-theme-material .ag-row-selected::before {
    background-color: #E4F3F7 !important;
}

/* .ag-theme-material .ag-row-selected .ag-cell {
    background-color: #F3F9FB !important;
} */

.ag-theme-material .ag-header-cell:hover {
    background-color: #BDDAE2 !important;
}

.ag-row-hover .ag-row-selected::before {
    background-color: #BDDAE2 !important;
}

I tried to modify the css of the AgGrid and the GridOptions but nothing happens.

I never used AgGrid, but in their documentation you can see :
// turns OFF row hover, it's on by default
const suppressRowHoverHighlight = true;
// turns ON column hover, it's off by default
const columnHoverHighlight = true;

<AgGridReact
    suppressRowHoverHighlight={suppressRowHoverHighlight}
    columnHoverHighlight={columnHoverHighlight}
/>

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-styles/#highlighting-rows-and-columns
At your service !
